# TypeScript IntRange which supports negative values

Tags: typescript

```
declare type Enumerate<N extends number, Acc extends number[] = []> = Acc['length'] extends N
    ? Acc[number]
    : Enumerate<N, [...Acc, Acc['length']]>

declare type IntRange<F extends number, T extends number> = Exclude<Enumerate<T>, Enumerate<F>>
```

This works for integer ranges like `IntRange<25, 200>` but when I give it a negative like `IntRange<-25, 200>` I get this error:

```
TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

How can I support integer ranges in TypeScript with negative numbers?

Comment: Not only `Enumerate` does not support negative number, it also does not support number >= 1000. You might want to re-think if you really want to base your program on this implementation.

Comment: What do you intend `Enumerate<,>` to be?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wv1QBm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This does seem to meet my needs. In my case, I'm looking to define ints in the range -25,200. However, if there is a better approach that works with larger ranges, I'd love to see that.

Comment: TS is not really intended to support such type-level math. There are approaches that *might* work with larger ranges (although unions can only hold about 10000 elements), but they are not necessarily "better", since they require more complicated type juggling. I don't know that it's worth going through the effort of producing that if your use case is ints in the range from -25 to 200. What do you want to see for the answer to this question as currently phrased?

Comment: Like, [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mLXAbm) will work for integers of quite large magnitude, but you will only get a range of about 1000 elements before it stops working (so you can get `IntRange<88888000, 88888005>` with no problem, but `IntRange<0, 2000>` will be an issue).  I'm not inclined to spend much more time worrying about other use cases unless you tell me you absolutely need that.  How should I proceed here?

Comment: In my use case, the actual range I need is rather small. (This is for Google Symbols, which have a "Grade" range of -25 - 200.) I'm just surprised that there is any limitation on how we can define ranges in TS.

Comment: Okay so when I write up my answer I will probably present the simplest version that works for your use case

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript does not natively support *numeric range types*; the current open discussion of this feature is [microsoft/TypeScript#54925](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54925), and it's not clear that this will ever be implemented.  Until and unless this happens, we'll need to use [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) to represent integer ranges.

Furthermore, TypeScript does not natively support *mathematical operations on numeric literal types*; the current open feature request for that is [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382).  Until and unless this happens, we'll need to use roundabout methods to get the type system to compute these things.

The two ways I know of to make the type system compute math-like operations on numeric literal types are:

- manipulation of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) and inspection of their `length` properties.  For example, appending or prepending elements to tuple types corresponds to incrementation, and concatenating tuple types corresponds to addition.  This is fairly straightforward, but limits the domain to non-negative integers of a fairly modest size.  Your `Enumerate` utility type works this way.
- manipulation of [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) and [more precise inference of parsed string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-inference-for-infer-types-in-template-string-types).  This lets you convert string literal types to numeric literal types and vice versa, and thus you can devise string-based implementations of mathematical operations, by serializing and deserializing the [`Number.prototype.toString(10)` representation of numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).  This can be complicated/ugly, but lets you potentially deal with large numbers, negative numbers, fractional number, etc.

In order for your `IntRange<F, T>` to work with negative numbers, therefore, you'll need to use template literals types, at least in part.  Here's a way to negate a number:

```
type Negate<N extends number> =
  N extends 0 ? 0 :
  `${N}` extends `-${infer S extends number}` ? S :
  `-${N}` extends `${infer S extends number}` ? S :
  never;

type X = Negate<1.23>;
// type X = -1.23
type Y = Negate<-1.2e-26>
// type Y = 1.2e-26
```

That works by parsing the string representation of a number and either peeling off or adding on an initial `"-"` character.

You can use that with `Enumerate` as follows:

```
type NonNegativeIntRange<F extends number, T extends number> =
  Exclude<Enumerate<T>, Enumerate<F>>

type NegativeIntRange<F extends number, T extends number> =
  Exclude<Negate<NonNegativeIntRange<Negate<T>, Negate<F>>> | F, T>;

type MixedIntRange<F extends number, T extends number> =
  F | Negate<Enumerate<Negate<F>>> | Enumerate<T>

type IntRange<F extends number, T extends number> =
  `${F}` extends `-${string}` ?
  `${T}` extends `-${string}` ?
  NegativeIntRange<F, T> :
  MixedIntRange<F, T> :
  NonNegativeIntRange<F, T>;
```

There are three valid ways to call `IntRange<F, T>`: either `F` and `T` are both negative, both non-negative, or `F` is negative and `T` is non-negative (the fourth possibility, where `F` is non-negative and `T` is negative, is invalid, because `F` must be less than or equal to `T`).  So we just check which of those situations we're in, and then delegate either to `NonNegativeIntRange` (your original implemenation), `NegativeIntRange` (change `F` to `Negate<T>` and `T` to `Negate<F>`, call `NonNegativeIntRange<F, T>`, and then `Negate` the result), or `MixedIntRange` (use `Enumerate` on `Negate<F>` and `T` and fiddle with endpoints).

Let's test it:

```
type X = IntRange<25, 30>;
//   ^?type X = 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29

type Y = IntRange<-30, -25>;
//   ^?type Y = -30 | -26 | -27 | -28 | -29

type Z = IntRange<-2, 3>;
//   ^?type Z = 0 | 1 | 2 | -2 | -1
```

So that will work for your question as asked.  Note that `Enumerate` is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) so it will necessarily only work situations where `T` and `F` have magnitudes less than 1000.

---

If you wanted it to work for larger magnitudes but still don't need situations where `T` minus `F` is bigger than 1000 (or 999 or something) then you'll need to abandon `Enumerate`'s tuple types and implement an integer increment/decrement operation with template literal types.  Maybe like this:

```
type Digit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type Next = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
type Inc<T extends number> =
  T extends -1 ? 0 :
  `${T}` extends `-${infer N extends number}` ? `-${Dec<N>}` extends
  `${infer M extends number}` ? M : never :
  `${T}` extends `${infer F extends number}${Digit}` ?
  `${T}` extends `${F}${infer D extends Digit}` ?
  `${D extends 9 ? Inc<F> : F}${Next[D]}` extends
  `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never : never :
  T extends 9 ? 10 : Next[T]

type Prev = [9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
type Dec<T extends number> =
  `${T}` extends `-${infer N extends number}` ? `-${Inc<N>}` extends
  `${infer M extends number}` ? M : never :
  `${T}` extends `${infer F extends number}${Digit}` ?
  `${T}` extends `${F}${infer D extends Digit}` ?
  `${D extends 0 ? Dec<F> extends 0 ? "" : Dec<F> : F}${Prev[D]}` extends
  `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never : never :
  T extends 0 ? -1 : Prev[T]
```

These are conditional types, where `Inc` on a negative number resolves to `Dec` and vice versa, and where the last digit is incremented or decremented and then, when necessary, a carry or borrow operation is performed on the previous digit recursively.  Then `Intrange` can be defined simply enough as

```
type IntRange<F extends number, T extends number, A extends number = never> =
  F extends T ? A : IntRange<Inc<F>, T, F | A>
```

where you just increment from `F` to `T`.   Let's test it:

```
type X = IntRange<25, 30>;
//   ^?type X = 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29

type Y = IntRange<-30, -25>;
//   ^?type Y = -30 | -26 | -27 | -28 | -29

type Z = IntRange<-2, 3>;
//   ^?type Z = 0 | 1 | 2 | -2 | -1

type W = IntRange<12345678, 12345703>
// type W = 12345678 | 12345679 | 12345680 | 12345681 | 12345682 | 12345683 | 12345684 | 12345685 | 
//    12345686 | 12345687 | 12345688 | 12345689 | 12345690 | 12345691 | 12345692 | 12345693 | 12345694 | 
//    12345695 | 12345696 | 12345697 | 12345698 | 12345699 | 12345700 | 12345701 | 12345702

type V = IntRange<-987654321, -987654315>
// type V = -987654321 | -987654320 | -987654319 | -987654318 | -987654317 | -987654316
```

That works even for relatively large numbers, although it would fail spectacularly for numbers written in scientific notation, or fractions, etc.

---

Handling arbitrarily large numbers would require more work.  So would handling ranges where `T` minus `F` is bigger than a thousand but less than about a hundred thousand.  Handling ranges where `T` minus `F` is bigger than a hundred thousand would require native support for numeric range types, since unions cannot hold more elements than about a hundred thousand.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgKLACukATiAC4D2dehRSjAnjJTfSYQAPADkkEAB6MIwACZRitAEYQ6AGiQBBCdNkKlYVXQDaAXSQBeJOYB8Vjp20mA5BlkBzRgAsXFqTLyiuIA-M4CxmaOnABcSFS0akJimiYAdBlamlqu7sBevmZmttE8fEiiEB7J4gH6ihFq9pbRRLV6QUgADEhhPTGtSAAGACS4ogC+Q7qBBkMAtGMAlsAAZmpIAMoz9YbGU71bSANORAtjk9N1naO4K+ts29cGjXQHYdsnp8AQAG5qAG58KVeMgABqSKwVKrJACMaQATABmWxApwAenRXFBSAhUPm8ORIPKAE1uNwoZVqjJhATERB5giAGwlDFYsrIElQwkM5nApwcirMYBUphLf4ASWAjAASiB8iIAGI7TqvTQAFRVLxUTQcp3ikngGGochECUENPVtk05qSNMVthKxOQosY4ogUtl8o8Sq1DR1GiQmue-qMupa+oohuNprEMJpomFrvdnrlCrj1JEVs0rqVjvsAB8kIqNaj+ZxBQBZJaSCByVPe30hvZqDV+lt0ZqDZVF3PCW0MBPxvOOpBFgfJK3A51IBvp5XNtVB9uvLv626Kg7N864KCMOgrDzvQa3dVbjpzRa7-eH4-65OS6Vpn3CEtB+xfJzV2v1p+N1+lscgyJiK8Ypn+86lkCM5glCc4vgiACsmhIl0ZZspwAB6ISCrB1hIWOSDMoRCIAOwkQAHCRACc5ZEIKXLWPBIjzKhmiMoh6GcJiWE4TijFIKxPRFoyTKEYy5EiQiVFSbRM4AFpwRBL6MihXFEDxRDYYKinWMJSCwiR4kIuJsLlhM5YkNAcCILOwDwAAIhA8DsDODlLB4SyMFC+mGUWJlFkihEACyEYhhFiUWklIDJSDUdBAo4pU0hQiYsKaAiKGaMFmjIUgTKaKRmgUZo1GaF0ZhohWOJSvAwjBheobGGupwNbMigEoc-QnmMZ5XI1wxXvcGztO1HbvINYxOXVoi2Oe7U9XcawbJWK4BhNq1xD8-xsJ+nCnvNuy3MNbALgNrwTFNHleXepwHf1Y0bpdS0PEgDntu5nmMLdTi3O9zbUYctWvh+xbPcljAmA5ZiHUEi0nRUa1hm80xhOIW1-BsGM7UB+ptbsgNhLC-TQtIJjqlEM4AAp0H8qVld0mjpURWVIDlSB5QVSBFTFlVuc59VI81ep3b1sOXssy1sKNuwXajk24MDs3i1A8NS0gq2Lut8ubcQmO7YtfXtsd6tnWNF1XV9P37WLD1HWMm6S69-0DZ9N2o4tLtjT0YTTSD7Y+0gABEQfHG9AsOmHju4DTfxQzDdtw+uTsjULagTejes49jWODPjnSB51cSx785OU4l5TMa+aeBvn2rI9kNdQtt4bdu2mphDocRV8DDoapoPbaE6FfgkpXrpkhKFoVVGlYlpfHlHhRHhf5kVEdF0k0XR2KkmPz4sWxglIepSCaUg2n8fiqHGWvEnGbFjJySPSC6XZ48qZlSAojPp9z+fC-IFfr5IyUlTLb0FAAdT3v+WEyJgqISZKREqBk4GIVIl0FE0QeKQO5KgxBsVYFIngYgwGRZCHEIor5PBFE-IoKIQgiiAU6EUKCmQ6hoU2H0KZBRFeSAsF-2YQwte5CGHRREdwgh1DSGCKZNRKhXDqK0PEdRJhyjWEyOohwvhGFODKN4co4ReDqJiKMZIhR0iRHoPkfA9BSjUHoIROAnEAA1aB6Z5jUQoqRJkiFgpIgRMzDxXifF+NhJxfhO9kCuOsEE7xvj-G0NiSE-x+kknxNhNItJoSH6eLiaE6KWSkSwiZNOIgFl8ATCAA)